# Aptana launcher icon missing in Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, aptana, ubuntu-12.04, aptana3

All,

After following this [great instructions](http://www.samclarke.com/2012/12/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-3-1-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/) to install Aptana in Ubuntu 12.04.1, the launcher icon is missing - its only a grey square with a question mark.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ticket currently opened against the behavior: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-2330.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the image is probably wrong. It should be easy to change the icon - there may be one in your installation folder or you can find one online to copy to the folder and use. Instructions for setting up and icon can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35347/how-do-i-get-custom-icon-for-apps-in-unity-dash) (and many other places). If you can right click on your launcher icon and choose to view it in a text editor, it should be obvious where the path to the icon is and to correct it so it is pointing to an existing (and readable) image.

Comment: The link to the image is:

Icon=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/icon.xpm

Where is the /opt/ folder in Ubuntu?

Comment: It would be at the very top, in the root directory with things like `/etc/` and `/usr/` (it will not be in your home directory). You can probably see that folder most easily by clicking `'File System'` in the `'Places'` bar on the left side of Nautilus (your file manager). Of course, you do not need to use the image at the path it came with, you can put an image anywhere on your computer as long as you change the path in the file you checked to point to the image you want. You can always type the path into the bar at the top of Nautilus too: `/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/` and see what is there.

Comment: Hmmm...the linked icon is in the right spot, is readable...I wonder what the issue is???

Comment: I haven't encountered this, but there are several thing to try - you can read about them [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40380/how-to-set-an-icon-for-eclipse).